Remove duplicates without changing the order of the names
consider the following data
Data ss;
infile datalines;
input ename $;
datalines;
Ram
Sita
Ram
Arjun
Sita
Ram
Arjun
;
run;

#output

Ram
Sita
Arjun

I know other approaches like by sorting the data by ename and then using the first., but this way we need to sort data and the output will be starting with Arjun, Ram and Sita. However, we need to retain the order like i mention in the expected output.
proc sort data=ss;
by ename;
run;

data want;
set ss;
by ename;
if first.ename;
run;


You could do it by using a hash table or array to keep track of what names have been read.  But if your data is not too big, you could also do it by adding a rownumber variable, and then you could sort, select the first.ename as you showed, and sort again to restore the order.
Data ss;
infile datalines;
input ename $;
datalines;
Ram
Sita
Ram
Arjun
Sita
Ram
Arjun
;
run;

data ss2 ;
  set ss ;
  rownum=_N_ ;
run ;

proc sort data=ss2 ;
  by ename rownum ;
run ;

data ss3 ;
  set ss2 ;
  by ename rownum ;
  if first.ename ;
run ;

proc sort data=ss3 ;
  by rownum ;
run ;

proc print data=ss3 ;
run ;

Or if you like SQL, after adding the rownum column you could do it like:
proc sql ; 
  create table want as
  select ename 
  from ss2
  group by ename
  having rownum=min(rownum)
  order by rownum
  ;
quit ;


You can use a hash to dedupe a data set in a single pass.
Example:
Data have;
infile datalines;
input ename $;
datalines;
Ram
Sita
Ram
Arjun
Sita
Ram
Arjun
;

data want ;
  set have ;
  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    declare hash h() ;
    h.defineKey('ename') ;
    h.defineDone() ;
  end ;
  if h.check() ne 0 ;
  h.add () ;  
run ;

